# Run publishing profile after successful IDE build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with several projects. One of the projects is an MVC4 app where I have two publishing profiles (debug & release) which outputs to filesystem.

Question is what do I need to do to run a PP automatically after an successful build started from the IDE?

I have tried to add as below but nothing happens.

Tnx!

[image: didnt work]